# Disambiguate between two constructors, when two type parameters are the same

Tags: c#

Given

```
class Either<A, B> {

    public Either(A x) {}
    public Either(B x) {}
}
```

How to disambiguate between the two constructors when the two type parameters are the same?

For example, this line:

```
var e = new Either<string, string>("");
```

Fails with:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Program.Either.Either(A)' and 'Program.Either.Either(B)'

I know if I had given the parameters different names (e.g. `A a` and `B b` instead of just `x`), I could use named parameters to disambiguate (e.g. `new Either<string, string>(a: "")`). But I'm interested in knowing how to solve this without changing the definition of `Either`.

Edit:

You *can* write a couple of smart constructors, but I'm interested in knowing if the `Either`'s constructors can be called directly without ambiguity. (Or if there are other "tricks" besides this one).

```
static Either<A, B> Left<A, B>(A x) {
    return new Either<A, B>(x);
}

static Either<A, B> Right<A, B>(B x) {
    return new Either<A, B>(x);
}

var e1 = Left<string, string>("");
var e2 = Right<string, string>("");
```

Comment: Why would you exactly need that..2 constructors of same type?

Comment: does the above example compiles and what is currently the behavior ?

Comment: Does your example even compile? I do not see a way around it. Usually I made a non-generic class Either, then add static factory methods that call a hidden constructor in the generic Either. Generic methods have a better type-parameter deduction.

Comment: @Amit To do exactly this, write an `Either` type. It's a simple way of encoding sum types in a language that doesn't have them. Here's an example: https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.4/base-4.9.1.0/Prelude.html#t:Either

Comment: @EhsanSajjad and @wigy, no, `new Either<string, string>("");` doesn't compile, that was my point. I've updated the post.

Comment: You're bringing this on yourself. You're trying to rely on a feature that disambiguates calls based on the type of the supplied parameter, but you've also set up a scenario where it's impossible to disambiguate these calls based on the type of the supplied parameter. You're sort of asking for it. It's an interesting fringe case though, one I hadn't yet considered. But this does not seem to be a bug in C#, it's more a logical consequence of your own setup.

Comment: The only way I can see that you can disambiguate the calls is to be able to "say" `A` or `B`. Since those are only "sayable" inside the class, I think your current static approach is unlikely to be bettered. (or, obviously, inside another generic with type parameters that map to A or B)

Comment: @wigy Yeah, I think having two `Right` and `Left` methods is the only way to solve this as well. The reason why `Either` is easier to implement in, say, Haskell or F#, is because Haskell forces all constructors to have different names, whereas C# does the opposite.

Comment: @dcastro: I guess you could get the constructors via reflection and then identify which one is which based on the method body somehow, then call the one you want

Comment: @dcastro it's not the *constructors* that allow Haskel or F# to create Either. For F# it's discriminated unions and pattern matching, as [this snippet shows](http://www.fssnip.net/ji/title/Either-in-F). C# also has pattern matching, but no discriminated unions

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `Left of 'a` and `Right of 'b` are what I was referring to as "constructors". Pattern matching is for deconstructing, that's a different issue.

Comment: Note that the issue you're bringing to light is not unique to generics. E.g. consider loading an `XDocument` from either a filepath to an XML file or an actual xml string. There's no way for the compiler to know _which_ method you want to use _based on_ the parameter type (in either case, it's a string). The only option is to disambiguate the methods based on a different signature (different method names, or a different combination of parameters) or an explicit parameter that makes you choose which approach to take (e.g. a boolean or an enum)

Comment: I find it a little strange that you're asking how to do something that -- in your edit -- apparently you know how to do.

Comment: It sounds a bit weird to create something that is either string, or a string.

Comment: @IllidanS4 values with the same type, but different meanings :) The `Left` constructor is usually used for returning an error, which could be a string explaining why the operation failed. The `Right` constructor is usually used for returning the result of a successful computation. E.g. `Either<string, string> GetUsername()`.

Comment: I see. Well, it's your code, but someone seeing the name *Either* (which is actually defined in ECMA TR/89 in the *System* namespace) may not expect some inherent meaning in the order of properties. This is more akin to a tuple typle.

Comment: @IllidanS4 this was me just playing around though :P there's already a very good implementation of Either for C# [here](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext). "Either" is actually a very well known pattern from Haskell, Scala, F#, Elm, Purescript etc, I believe OCaml has something similar too

Comment: @IllidanS4 Side note: it's interesting that you brought up tuples! They do look very similar, but they're actual dual to one another! Tuples are product types (this and that), whereas Either is a sum type (this or that)!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> How to disambiguate between the two constructors when the two type parameters are the same?

I'll start by not answering your question, and then finish it up with an actual answer that lets you work around this problem.

You don't have to because **you should never get yourself into this position in the first place**.  It is a design error to create a generic type which can cause member signatures to be unified in this manner. Never write a class like that.

If you go back and read the original C# 2.0 specification you'll see that the original design was to have the compiler detect generic types in which it was *in any way possible* for this sort of problem to arise, and to make the class declaration illegal. This made it into the published specification, though that was an error; the design team realized that this rule was too strict because of scenarios like:

```
class C<T> 
{
  public C(T t) { ... }
  public C(Stream s) { ... deserialize from the stream ... }
}
```

It would be bizarre to say that this class is illegal because you might say `C<Stream>` and then be unable to disambiguate the constructors. Instead, a rule was added to overload resolution which says that if there's a choice between `(Stream)` and `(T where Stream is substituted for T)` then the former wins.

Thus the rule that this kind of unification is illegal was scrapped and it is now allowed. However it is a very, very bad idea to make types that unify in this manner.  The CLR handles it poorly in some cases, and it is confusing to the compiler and the developers alike.  For example, would you care to guess at the output of this program?

```
using System;
public interface I1<U> {
    void M(U i);
    void M(int i);
}

public interface I2<U> {
    void M(int i);
    void M(U i);
}

public class C3: I1<int>, I2<int> {
    void I1<int>.M(int i) {
        Console.WriteLine("c3 explicit I1 " + i);
    }
    void I2<int>.M(int i) {
        Console.WriteLine("c3 explicit I2 " + i);
    }
    public void M(int i) { 
        Console.WriteLine("c3 class " + i); 
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void Main() {
        C3 c3 = new C3();
        I1<int> i1_c3 = c3;
        I2<int> i2_c3 = c3;
        i1_c3.M(101);
        i2_c3.M(102);
    }
}
```

If you compile this with warnings turned on you will see the warning I added explaining why this is a really, really bad idea.

> No, really: How to disambiguate between the two constructors when the two type parameters are the same?

Like this:

```
static Either<A, B> First<A, B>(A a) => new Either<A, B>(a);
static Either<A, B> Second<A, B>(B b) => new Either<A, B>(b);
...
var ess1 = First<string, string>("hello");
var ess2 = Second<string, string>("goodbye");
```

**which is how the class should have been designed in the first place**. The author of the `Either` class should have written

```
class Either<A, B> 
{
  private Either(A a) { ... }
  private Either(B b) { ... }
  public static Either<A, B> First(A a) => new Either<A, B>(a);
  public static Either<A, B> Second(B b) => new Either<A, B>(b);
  ...
}
...
var ess = Either<string, string>.First("hello");
```

Comment: Aren't `First` and `Second` the same as `Left` and `Right` in the OPs question?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: That edit was added after I'd already started composing my answer.

Comment: The static methods he provided arent within the class definition. Simple as that. Everyone can write those methods outside of the class body. He only suggests putting them in there.

Comment: @musefan: I'm pretty sure this answers the question. That it answers it with a technique apparently already known to the original poster does not make it an incorrect answer. I note that the OP added the fact that **they already knew the answer to their question** after I had started composing an answer to the question. It is a mystery to me why someone would ask a question that they already knew the answer to.

Comment: @EricLippert Regarding my edit, I'll take the blame. I came up with that solution quickly after posting the question - I probably should have added that as an answer to my own question (for future readers), rather than editing the question. Even so, I wanted to know whether there were other, perhaps in some way better, solutions.

Comment: @dcastro: Well good for you for coming up with that solution; it is by no means immediately obvious!

Comment: @Eric: Sorry, on review I have overlooked that your first set of static method were intended for use outside of the class. I thought you were only suggesting to change the class itself as per your final block of code. I now agree that it does answer the requirement of not having to change the class definition. Whether it's still valid after the question edit I could go either way on, so I will just avoid an opinion on that. I agree with you on the purpose of the question in the first place though, which is what I originally comments on the question anyway

Comment: @EricLippert Thank you for the example, and the insight into how CLR handles this. The warning says "Which interface is actually chosen is implementation-dependent" - is this saying that the result depends on the order in which you declare `M(U)` and `M(int)`? Is this detailed in the C# spec, or is it left up to the compiler implementers?

Comment: @dcastro Bizarrely enough yes, it depends on source code order. It is not in the spec. The compiler does the best it can but the decision about what methods are bound to what interface slots is determined by the CLR implementation. There actually is insufficient granularity in the interface implementation tables for the compiler to say which it prefers! This is a small design flaw in the implementation of generics; the cost of fixing it is too high for such an obscure scenario.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I could think of would be to use reflection to iterate each constructor and then determine which one should be used based on the method body.

Of course this is way over the top and you should really just refactor your class, but it is a working solution.

It requires that you identify the `byte[]` for the method body that you want to use and 'hard code' that into the program (or read from file etc.). Of course you need to be very cautious that the method body may change over time, for example if the class is modified at any point.

```
// You need to set (or get from somewhere) this byte[] to match the constructor method body you want to use.
byte[] expectedMethodBody = new byte[] { 0 };

Either<string, string> result = null; // Will hold the result if we get a match, otherwise null.
Type t = typeof(Either<string, string>); // Get the type information.

// Loop each constructor and compare the method body.
// If we find a match, then we invoke the constructor and break the loop.
foreach (var c in t.GetConstructors())
{
    var body = c.GetMethodBody();
    if (body.GetILAsByteArray().SequenceEqual(expectedMethodBody))
    {
        result = (Either<string, string>)c.Invoke(new object[] { "123" });
        break;
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer**: Although I have tested this code briefly and it seems to work, I am really sceptical about how reliable it is. I do not know enough about the compiler to be comfortable in saying the method body wont change on a re-compile even if the code isn't changed. It may be that it would become more reliable if this class was defined in a pre-compiled DLL, again I don't know for sure though.

---

There *may* be other information you could get via reflection that might make it easier to identify the correct constructor. However, this was the first that came to mind and I haven't really looked into any other possible options at this time.

It would be much simpler if we could rely on the order of the constructors, but [as quoted from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h70wxday(v=vs.110).aspx), it is not reliable:

> The GetConstructors method does not return constructors in a particular order, such as declaration order. Your code must not depend on the order in which constructors are returned, because that order varies.

Comment: Good try, but you can do it without reflection.